# Macbook Pro - How do we terminate ALL ESTABLISHED connections?

Tags: terminal, mac, tcp

How do I terminate ALL the ESTABLISHED tcp connections in Terminal?

I can use the command below to get a list of active & established connections:

`netstat -anvp tcp | awk 'NR<3 || /ESTABLISHED/‘`

I would like to terminate the connections one by one OR all at the same time. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to shut down the os or just disconnect all network interfaces?

Comment: To terminate all remote connections at once, disconnect the ethernet cable or disable WiFi :-) But the bigger problem here is: what are you trying to accomplish with this, which problem would it solve?

Comment: @bmike - I donot want to disconnect network interfaces or disconnect Ethernet cables etc..  All I'm trying to do is stay connected while disconnecting a few TCP connections

Comment: But why do you want to disconnect these connections? What is the _actual_ problem you're trying to solve? This whole question feels strange, you're trying to do something very unusual so we want to understand the reasoning behind this: maybe we can suggest a better way to solve the problem.

Comment: Kill the process responsible for the connection then :-)

Comment: @darkdust - I see a few suspicious connections which are in ESTABLISHED state.  So I would like to terminate these connections. Note that the PID keeps changing everytime/day so I cannot just kill a process with the PID. Instead, I'm trying to terminate the ESTABLISHED connections. If it's a authorised connection then it wont be killed.

Comment: @nohillside - I cannot just kill a process using the PID or so as the process re-appears shortly. So I'm looking to kill the connection for all ACTIVE established connections.

Comment: You can easily write a short script that is then going to kill the process, but I'd first try to learn what program is responsible for it. To learn that, try `lsof -iTCP -sTCP:ESTABLISHED +c 0` which prints the command to which the connections belong (and where they're connected to).

Comment: It would really help to find good answers if you could share some details about the practical problem you are trying to solve here. Please edit this directly into the question.

Comment: Having said that: If the process reappers after you killed it, chances are high that these processes will also quickly reestablish their network connections in case you somehow manage to terminate them (which I still doubt is actually possible).

Comment: @DarkDust - thanks kind of helped to get the program associated with the connection. I will need a script that I can run which can simply terminate these connections.  If they are genuine one's they wont terminate with a pkill or other command

Answer (score 0):

The fact that a connection has been made means that connection is already genuine. I would probably look to block connections that reappear with an access control list or firewall software like Little Snitch.

- https://obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html

It is superb at this task and will help you begin to wrangle all the genuine and intentional connections and let you put rules and values so you can manage the connections and control them at the source. There are very few connections you can kill and have stay dead in practice.